# Run a NPAPI plugin with granted privileges (firebreath)

Tags: c++, plugins, npapi, firebreath

My NPAPI plugin needs root privileges to run. I'm wondering if there is any portable way to do it with firebreath.

If not, I took a look at [how Firesheep does it](https://github.com/codebutler/firesheep/blob/master/backend/src/linux_platform.cpp), but it requires a binary file and a launcher (which is the plugin). How to tell `cmake` to build the binary and the plugin separately ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to launch another process and have that do the work; as a plugin you don't own your own process, and you can't change the rights that a process runs with anyway, you have to relaunch it.

There is no "portable" way to do this; you'll have to write platform specific code for each platform. You can add another cmake project just by creating a new directory with a CMakeLists.txt file, etc, and using add_directory to include it. There are [plenty](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html) of [tutorials](http://mathnathan.com/2010/07/11/getting-started-with-cmake/) [available](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/wiki/TutorialCMake) for [doing](http://code.google.com/p/cmaketutorial/) this, and of course the [CMake Documentation](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html) is helpful.

When you add a new project with cmake it'll just show up as an additional project alongside the others that FireBreath already has, so it can be built together with the rest of what you're doing.